# How to give all inputs in a div the value attribute and use their current value as value content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

in the below example,by clicking the log button,it shows in the log the div's markup which consists of inputs without a predefined value attribute like this: `<input><input><input><input><input><input>`,even if i type some text in the inputs it logs the same thing.

i want to use the button #add to give all inputs the value attribute,and the content should be the current value of them,so next time i'll click log should show this : `<input value"CURRENT VALUE.."><input value"CURRENT VALUE.."><input value"CURRENT VALUE.."><input value"CURRENT VALUE.."><input value"CURRENT VALUE.."><input value"CURRENT VALUE..">`

is there a simple method to do this with jquery ?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#log', function() {
  console.log($('div').html())
});

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {

  //GIVE ALL INPUTS THE "value" ATTRIBUTE AND SET THEIR CURRENT VALUE AS CONTENT

});
```

```css
input,
button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="log">LOG HTML</button>
  <button id="add">ADD VALUE ATTRIBUTE</button>
  <div>
    <input><input><input><input><input><input>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code-wise this is easy to solve, as the answers show. Yet this has a smell of you trying to do something wrong out of misunderstanding the `value` attribute.

It only serves a single purpose: Setting the **initial** value of an `input` declaratively, that is, in the markup. It is not meant to be refreshed as soon as the input's value changes.

The DOM element *property* that synchronizes with the `value` *attribute* is `element.defaultValue`.

That being said, here's simple plain vanilla Javascript solution:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

document
  .getElementById('add')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const input of inputs) {
      input.defaultValue = input.value;
    }
  });

document
  .getElementById('log')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    document
      .getElementById('html-log-area')
      .textContent = [...inputs].reduce((acc, {outerHTML: o}) => `${acc}${o}\n`, '');
  });
```

```css
input,
button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 2px;
}

#html-log-area {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  border: 4px dashed lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button id="log">LOG HTML</button>
<button id="add">ADD VALUE ATTRIBUTE</button>
<div>
  <input><input><input>
</div>
<br/>
<pre id="html-log-area"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Connexo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738582/4665) is great and you should note that in the modern browser environment jquery's usefulness is waning.

For a more "pure jquery" answer see below:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#log', function() {
  console.log($('div').html())
});

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  //Iterate the inputs
  $(".dynamicAttribute input").each(function() {
    //If we have a value
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      //Add the value attribute
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input,
button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="log">LOG HTML</button>
  <button id="add">ADD VALUE ATTRIBUTE</button>
  <div class="dynamicAttribute">
    <input><input><input><input><input><input>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```